# 7-segment display BCD decoder with normal hex values

Tags: integrated-circuit, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I'm trying to find a 7-segment display BCD decoder IC with normal HEX display.

Most of the decoders that I managed to find have an output like this:

[image]

These hex values just look awful. I previously did this decoder on FPGA, and the output looked like this:

```
A b C d E F
```

Does anyone know some BCD decoder IC with "normal" HEX display?

Comment: A binary-coded decimal decoder wouldn't do that - if it did it would be called a seven-segment hexadecimal decoder instead. And apparently they don't make those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [7 segment binary to hex](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351606/7-segment-binary-to-hex)

Comment: Look at this datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7447a.pdf

Comment: [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16034/41125) (not exactly a duplicate) and its answers mention the MC14495-P1 (seemingly difficult to get hold of, hence the question) and a Fairchild part DM9368 ([data sheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/DM9368.pdf)) which I have no idea about the availability of.

Comment: Used to use a TTL PROM or MOS EPROM for this.  Today I would probably use a PIC with 11 or more i/o pins.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any such IC, I will stick with the standard ones, and just won't use hex values. @AlmostDone Good suggestion using a PIC with 11 or more I/O pins!

Comment: I'm seeing the MC14495 chip available on Amazon now.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea on the availability of these chips:

- V40511 (this one is an old DDR (eastern Germany) part, so definitely 
  gone)
- [MC14495](http://www.riana.com/electronics/docs/MC14495.pdf)
- [DM9368](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/D/M/9/3/DM9368.shtml)
- D345
- D346
- D348
- CMOS 4311 or 4368
- 74C915 ?
- [ICM7211 / ICM7212](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ICM7211-ICM7212.pdf) (not the A variant)

The [TIL311](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/588/til311-e4-519224.pdf) is a complete hexadecimal display - might be an alternative.